# Knockout JS Inline Ternary

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to check if some data is empty, and then either display the data, or a message.

I've got the following code at the moment which displays my text and adds ellipses to the end of it.

```
<p data-bind="text:$data['Preview Text'] + '...'"></p>
```

Ideally, this would check the `preview text` and if there is none then it would return another message instead. I've had a go at making this happen but I can't get it to work.

```
<p data-bind="text: preview() ? $data['Preview Text'] + '...' : 'aaaaaaaa'"></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first advice would be to not place this logic in your data-bind, but in your viewmodel. It's easier to debug, easier to change, and keeps your HTML readable.

I'm assuming you have an observable string that holds your preview text, but can be empty. (It would help if, next time, you'd show your actual javascript model as well)

To generate a label, you can use a `ko.computedObservable` or `ko.pureComputed`. An example:

```
var originalLabel = ko.observable("A label");
var displayLabel = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return originalLabel() ? originalLabel() + "..." : "No Label";
});
```

`displayLabel` updates whenever `originalLabel` updates. If the original label is empty, it returns the default text `"No Label"`. If the original label is not empty, it adds `"..."` to it.

A working example:

```js
var VM = function() {

  this.originalLabel = ko.observable("Initial Text");
  this.displayLabel = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var originalLabel = this.originalLabel();
    return originalLabel ? originalLabel + "..." : "No label set";
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-bind="value: originalLabel, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />

<div>Generated value: <strong data-bind="text: displayLabel"></strong>
</div>
```